# Image stretching within storyboards. No results at all

Tags: iphone, ios

Im not sure what I'm doing wrong here or in fact how I could be doing anything wrong at all. No matter what I enter into the stretching section of the menu nothing changes.

I'm wanting to stretch out the center of the image so that the corners appear correct.

So here is the button.(myimage.png) Its 200x200px the corners are 75px wide. and the middle is 50px(what needs to be stretched). So with the stretching thing on iOS taking 0-1.0 I gave it as that.

Whats wrong here?

(full size screen shot of settings) https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgMiQ.png

[image]

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do stretched images in IB, you have to create the image in code using `UIImage`'s `resizableImageWithCapInsets`

Comment: That looks like its the case, but why are the options even there? I guess if it was then settings would be under image rather than view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set the image as resizable in code using:

```
myImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(36,36,36,36)];
```

I am not sure what the "stretching" options in view are there for, it may be something left over from porting the tools over from OSX

Comment: Looking in to this now. I'll be a minute :) Thank you!

Comment: `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,75,0,75)`

Comment: I tried both but it didn't turn out as expected. Instead it made the button massive and added some sort of stork to the top of it :P http://i.imgur.com/q8wL1k9.png

Comment: Seems like you are stretching the image vertically. Those numbers were for horizontal stretching.

Comment: I do want to stretch it horizontally the button is normal height. :)

Comment: Did you reset the storyboard stretch? `x:0 y:0 w:1 h:1`

Comment: Yeh I did. Maybe I should have the image the same size as the default button.. do you know what that is? or default and 2x?

Comment: Button should be halfsize of the image if you are using retina.

Comment: I just used defaults of 36 and 72@2x with (18, 18, 18, 18) and it looks perfect. xD (Do you want to modify your answer Dan and I will accept it)